# Using grep and wc with wildcards on a file

Tags: regex, grep, wildcard, wc

**Display:**

1) number of students whose last name is Yang.

**My work:**

1) grep "[Yang] [A-Za-z]* [A-D][+]* [A-Za-z]*" students.txt | wc -l

**Comment:** Regex seems ok but outputs 6 instead of 3

Comment: One question per question, please; there will be duplicates for all four. But briefly, (1) `grep -iw`; (2) `grep -c`; (3) + (4) also, properly quote your regex.

Comment: shortened to 1 question

Comment: asking one question and getting 4 answers - You must be in luck ;-)

Comment: I actually just solved them all except 4) ..... my answer for that one is "grep "[^Yang] [A-Za-z]* [A-D][+]* [A-Za-z]*" students.txt | wc -l"   it outputs 4 instead of 3 any idea why?

Comment: Yup - the hat inside the brackets means something different - try the grep without the word count - and try tme out at regexr.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) add a space inside pattern, so Johnson is hidden
grep -i "John " students.txt

2) Wildcards can never be better than exact value - stick with it

3) look at 1 - add a space, so it is a wildcard like " A \| A+ " i escaped the pipe sign, because i use double quotes and not single quotes (i believe)

4) Yang is lastname, so it is first - that You can check for  with the hat on: '^Yang'

regular expressions are fun - and sometimes time consuming.
There are good places on the net - try http://regexr.com/